# UITableviewCell values are changing

Tags: iphone

I am new in iPhone development. I am using UItableview for showing list. 
And able to show all items successfully.
But they changed when I scroll tableview.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code in cellForRowAtIndexPath method of tableview

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {

cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please give me more information to show your case clearly.
Have a look at this function first because all rows are generated from here!

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
  static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";

  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

  if (cell == nil) {
      cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
  }

  cell.textLabel.text = [recipes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  return cell;
  }

Check whether each row is exist,unless just reuse it later.